# Terminate child processes in OS X Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, osx-mountain-lion, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to bundle Apache in my sandboxed application. Starting it works but I'm finding some issues stopping it. By either directly calling 'kill' or using "apachectl -k stop" I keep receiving a "deny signal" sandbox error.

Is there any way of accomplishing what I'm trying? Are all signals denied?

I'm testing it in the latest version of OS X 10.8.

Comment: is it possible to launch separate tasks or processes from a sandboxed application?

Comment: Yes. They inherit the main application sandbox entitlements.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to terminate other apps in sandbox, but you can use the `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` function, from Service Management framework, to start and stop other apps.

See [Adding Login Items Using the Service Management Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html), if you want to use this method.